# Solution of this ODE comprising Airy functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following ODE (and initial condition):

$$Y\hat{W}_1 = M +  \hat{W}_{1,YY} $$
$$\hat{W}_1 (0)=0$$

where $M$ is a constant, has a solution of the Gi Scorer's function form. However, I have been told that the full solution is of this kind

$\hat{W}_1=a Gi(Y) + b Ai(Y)$

with a and b constants. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the equation

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2 f(y)}{{\rm d}y^2} - y f(y) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

is

$$
f(y) = \alpha {\rm Ai}(y) + \beta {\rm Bi}(y) \tag{2}
$$

where $\rm Ai$ is the [Airy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) function and $\rm Bi$ is the associated Airy function of the second kind. The solution to the problem

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2 f(y)}{{\rm d}y^2} - y f(y) = \color{red}{-m} \tag{3}
$$

is therefore

$$
y(x) = \alpha {\rm Ai}(y) + \beta {\rm Bi}(y) + \color{red}{g_m(y)} \tag{4} 
$$

where $g_m(x)$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous problem, which in this case is not trivial at all. This is what Wolfram Alpha gives as a result

\begin{eqnarray}
f(y) = \alpha \text{Ai}(y)+\beta \text{Bi}(y) +
 \left\{ 3 3^{5/6} \pi  m y \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \text{Ai}(y)
   \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{y^3}{9}\right)-3
   \sqrt[3]{3} \pi  m y \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \text{Bi}(y) \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{y^3}{9}\right)+3
   \sqrt[6]{3} \pi  m y^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \text{Ai}(y)
   \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{y^3}{9}\right)+3^
   {2/3} \pi  m y^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 \text{Bi}(y) \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{y^3}{9}\right)\right\}/\left\{2
   7 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\right\}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Do you know if either the homogeneous solution or the particular one can be expressed in terms of the Scorer's Gi function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorer%27s_function I mean, in some sense Gi is a combination of Ai and Bi....

Comment: You could write

$$
{\rm Hi}(x) = \frac{3 x^2 \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{x^3}{9}\right)+4 \pi 
   \text{Bi}(x)}{6 \pi }
$$

and

$$
{\rm Gi}(x) = \frac{-\frac{1}{40} x^5 \,
   _1F_4\left(1;\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},\frac{11}{6};\frac{x^
   6}{1296}\right)-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \,
   _1F_4\left(1;\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3};\frac{x^6
   }{1296}\right)+\frac{\pi  \text{Bi}(x)}{3}}{\pi }
$$

From this  you can tell that you can always write the solution above in terms of these two functions